# Using mutt and thunderbird together

Tags: mutt, thunderbird

I'd love to use both `thunderbird` and `mutt` together. At times I just want a GUI over CLI or the reverse. I also love `thunderbird`'s search and contact features. I especially love its mail filtering capabilities.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should install an IMAP server on your machine. Then both MUA's can have access to your mail via IMAP.